# Every singelton is bounded in a topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove that every singelton (one point set $\{x\}$) is bounded in a topological vector space.

I can't see it so easily. It is obvous that given a $V$ neighberhood of $0$, there is $t>0$ such that $x\in tV$ (since $X=\cup nV$), but why would $x\in sV$ for every $s>t$?

Thanks

**P.S:**
I understood that the definition i'm working with isn't the standart.
My definition of a set $X$ being bounded is that for every $V$ neighborhood of $0$, there is $t>0$ such that for all $s>t:\:X\subset sV$.

Comment: Is there a metric?

Comment: not neccessirily

Comment: @AaronMaroja, isn't required: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_%28topological_vector_space%29.

Comment: So the complementary idea works.

Comment: I edited and gave a clarification on the definition i'm working with

Comment: The definition of a bounded set (in a TVS) that you use is the standard definition.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $0$. Then there is $U\subset V$ balanced neighborhood of $0$.

Then $\exists t>0:\:\{x\}\subset tU$. then for any $s>t$ we have $t/s<1$ so $tU\subset sU\subset sV$.